# How can I map a middle click to control click?

Tags: mouse

Just started to use a Mac for my new job and not being able to use the middle button to open links in a new tab is killing me. I know I can press control and do a regular click but it's not the same. I know the Mac knows I'm trying to do something because it beeps at me when I press the middle button on my mouse. Is there any hope?

Note I tried the trick about setting [expose dashboard to -](http://arnab.org/blog/getting-middle-click-work-tab-browsing-mac-os-x) but it didn't work.

Comment: I would love to have this for my MacBook Pro.  I use 2 finger tap/click for right clicks and it would be great if control click emulated a middle click!

Answer (score 5):

Try holding the <kbd>Command</kbd> button instead. A <kbd>Command</kbd> click is a middle click. <kbd>Control</kbd> clicks give you a right click.

What kind of Mac? If you're using a Magic Mouse you can use a program like [MagicPrefs](http://magicprefs.com/) to turn a three finger click into a <kbd>Command</kbd> click. If you're using the Magic Trackpad or the built-in trackpad on a MacBook/MacBook Pro there is a program called [MiddleClick](http://clement.beffa.org/labs/projects/middleclick/) I've used that adds a three finger tap/click ability to map to the <kbd>Command</kbd> click.

Comment: This is where my "answer" was meant to go :) :       
I love you Chealion... MiddleClick does the trick for me. I can now close tabs and open links in new tabs with trackpad taps!!!

Comment: @calavera: Ha! Just glad to help. MiddleClick made life browsing much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Karabiner can be used to map mouse buttons. I haven't tested the following but it should be something like:

```
    {
      "description": "MouseButton3 to Ctrl+MouseButton1",
      "manipulators": [
        {
          "type": "basic",
          "from": {
            "pointing_button": "button3",
            "modifiers": {
              "optional": [
                "caps_lock"
              ]
            }
          },
          "to": [
            {
              "pointing_button": "button1"
              "modifiers": [
                "control"
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

If you want to limit this mapping to the browser, something like the following in the `manipulators` block should do it:

```
          "conditions": [
            {
              "type": "frontmost_application_if",
              "bundle_identifiers": ["^com\\.google\\.Chrome$"]
            }
          ],
```